# JSF Servlet Arch Help needed

Tags: java, architecture, jsf, servlets

i want a mechanism in my web app as described below:

user will enter mydomain.com/CompanyName , depending upon the CompanyNameit will show its logo and its customized page, and i will take that parsed parameter in session again upon each request i will compare the parsed CompanyName and one stored in session , and if they matched then application will show the requested page with user's data.else it will be redirected to login page.
and the main thing is i want this thing in JSF arch.

i tried taking a servlet that will resolve all request and it will parse and then will dispatch the request to prefered servlet,but problem is it goes in loop as again it resolves to the same controller servlet,

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do this via a phase listener. You can define a global one in `faces-config.xml` (or using annotations, if JSF 2.0 is used)

```
<lifecycle>
    <phase-listener>com.yourcompany.CompanyPhaseListener</phase-listener>
</lifecycle>
```

There you have access to the `FacesContext`, from which you can obtain the current request URI. Parse it and store the appropriate attributes in the request, which you can later read on your pages.

The phase listener is executed on the specified phase(s), and perhaps you should choose `RENDER_RESPONSE`

For affecting the way your URLs appear in the browser, check [PrettyFaces](http://ocpsoft.com/prettyfaces/).

Comment: but the problem here is,
how can i achieve mydomain.com/something/companyname/pages/somepage.jsf pattern ?

the URL in browser must include companyName .

Comment: as a note - why don't you use a subdomain, i.e. - `companyname.yourdomain.com` (and see my update)

Comment: no i want to handle it using URL pattern only, can't we just manage it using JSF only, without preetyFaces?

Comment: i tried pretty faces, it works fine except in a case, where the view is resolved from faces-config.xml then the URL pattern won't be the required one,
i means using pretty faces we can resolve view from pattern but what when i resolve view from faces-config.xml and i want my desired URL pattern ?

Comment: here i have attached the sample application i have created using prettyFaces,
access this URL.
yourserver:port/MavenJSFSample/companyName/login
click button
it wi get the
yourserver:port/MavenJSFSample/companyName/home.jsf

i want some thing like

yourserver:port/MavenJSFSample/companyName/home



http://www.4shared.com/file/M9h7dt9S/MavenJSFSample.html]MavenJSFSample.zip

Comment: PrettyFaces does work, but you need to use the built-in navigation: http://ocpsoft.com/docs/prettyfaces/snapshot/en-US/html_single/#navigation.actions

Answer (score 1):

> i tried taking a servlet that will resolve all request and it will parse and then will dispatch the request to prefered servlet,but problem is it goes in loop as again it resolves to the same controller servlet,

Use a `Filter` instead. It by default doesn't listen on forwarded requests, so you won't get an infinite loop on forwarding.

Comment: thats what pretty faces does,

using this pattern i am facing a problem,


 it works fine except in a case, where the view is resolved from faces-config.xml then the URL pattern won't be the required one, i means using pretty faces we can resolve view from pattern but what when i resolve view from faces-config.xml and i want my desired URL pattern ?

Comment: here i have attached the sample application i have created using prettyFaces,
access this URL.
http://yourserver:port/MavenJSFSample/companyName/login
click button
it wi get the
http://yourserver:port/MavenJSFSample/companyName/home.jsf

i want some thing like

http://yourserver:port/MavenJSFSample/companyName/home

http://www.4shared.com/file/M9h7dt9S/MavenJSFSample.html]MavenJSFSample.zip

Comment: BalusC expecting for your comment.